# Using a part of a existing collection in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on migrating stats calcul from php to node.js. The previous develloper made one collection per client, and all collection does not follow the same schema.

However, the part I need for calcul are the same on all collection, so what I am trying to do is a "uncomplete" schema like this:

```
S_logs.web =  new mongoose.Schema({
        /*
        user_ip     : String,
        user_id     : String,
        user_agent  : String,
        */
        canal_id    : String,
        theme_id    : String,
        video_id    : String,
        time        : Number,
        /*
        action      : String,
        is_newuser  : String,
        operator    : String,
        template    : String,
        catalogue   : String,
        */
        referer     : String,
        /*
        from        : String,
        request     : String,
        smil        : String,
        smil_path   : String
        */
    }, {
        collection: db_web
});

M_logs.web = mongoose.model(db_web, S_logs.web, db_web);
```

The commented fields are field that only exist (under that name or form) only in one collection. Uncommented fields are thoses I need and exist in all collection.

If all fields are uncommented, everythings works, but when I comment out thoses fields, it seems the collections isn t recognized, even thought I gave the name of the collection.

Am I missing a flag/option that allow me for such schema? Or am I doomed to make "all fields" schema for each clients?

EDIT:

When I speak of "uncomplete" schema, it s more "select only thoses fields I know exist in the middle of all I don t know", I do not need to put data in the collection, that's why I find odd that MongoDB doesn t have anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose can act in a "schemaless" mode. There are some consequences such as missing accessors for each of the fields and needing to specify those "explicitly" though:

```
 S_logs.web = new Schema({}, { strict: false });

 M_logs.web = mongoose.model( db_web, S_logs.web, db_web );
```

So that means when you access a "field/property" in your document you need to use the `.get()` method instead of a autogenerated accessor, such as :

```
 M_logs.web.find({}, function(err,logs) {
     logs.forEach(function(log) {
         var canal_id = log.get("canal_id");
         // do something with that value
     });
 });
```

This is useful if all documents do not conform to a schema pattern that is consistent, but understand that the auto-generated objects cannot have the same convenient interface when dealing with this level of "polymorphism" as it is not something supported by mongoose.

Comment: Can I still use queries as if I was in "shema" mode? Also, can I still specify a shema or do I just need to tell mongoose that I don t use strict mode?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Well you can use "Mixed" as a "type" but the effects are mush the same. As I said, Mongoose does not "directly" support "polymorphism" in this sense, so it is really best to approach this as  "schemaless" as suggested. You can otherwise implement "a lot of code" to do this with implicit accessors as would be the normal "consistent" data model case. Your choice.

Comment: Since I m only reading data, all I had to change was to had `.get()` : )